# Where do I find the file in wordpress /PHP project that I can edit the menu?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have project which was done in php. But I couldn't find the menu bar. In inspect element I find that it comes from navigation.html. But I couldn't find this file. Can any one help me with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find the location of wordpress installation.
Then look inside wp-content/themes/.
Check the `header.php` file to see how the menu is being setup.